# Visual Studio timer problem

Tags: winforms, timer

I couldn't find any explanation for the following problem. Hope you to help me to know the solution...

Let's make a new windows appliaction (using any version of VS), and add a ***button***, ***timer*** (we modify the interval to become = **10**), and a ***label*** (with initial text = "**0**").

write the following code in the timer:

> label1.Text =
>   (Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) +
>   1).ToString();

write the following code in the button:

> timer1.Enabled = true;

The label should show an incremental counter starting from 0.

Logically, each 100 counts should consume 1 second, but this is **NOT** the truth.
What happens is that each 100 counts consume **a little bit more than 1 second !!!**

**What is the cause of this behavior????!!!**

Thank you very much for your listenning, and waiting for your reply because I really searched for an explenation but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why do you label that Visual Studio? It has no relevance to Visual Studio - unless you also order Pizza by the manufacturer of your knifes. It should be labelled .NET / Winforms etc.

Comment: yes you are right, I could have done that... But I wanted to clarify that this 'week point' has not removed for 5 years...

Comment: Re-tagged to remove the visual studio tags, and added "timer", since that's what this is actually about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, it is limited to an accuracy of 55 ms.

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

See the Remarks section:  [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

Comment: There should be a green outline of a large checkmark under the vote count for this answer. Simply click the checkmark's outline and this answer will be marked as accepted.